# Does gtk support display multiple videos with gstreamer?

Tags: c, gstreamer, gtk3

I've been working on a project that requires me to display multiple videos at the same time.

It's the first time I use `gstreamer`.

At first, I tried to use `videosink` to display one and use `opencv` and `cairo` to display other one, 
but this failed.

And I tried to add more drawing area and use same video sink, but it came out that videos were displayed on same drawing area widget.

I also tried to add more `gstvideooverlay`, but this could not work.

Is it possible to display multiple videos on different drawing area widgets at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

> but this could not work.

is not very descriptive. It sounds like you are doing something wrong here.

On the other hand if you are developing a GTK gui application I would use `gtksink` or `gtkglsink` respectively. With these you can simply set `GtkWidgets` into your GUI.

Comment: Thank you @FlorianZwoch. Sorry for replying it after couple months. So I tried to display multiple videos on gtkwindow. But for the drawing callback function example in gstreamer tutorial 5th, it need window handle instead of widget handle, which means I can only use one widget (gtk.DrawingArea) to get window handle and display. Or the only one video will play while the other video will freeze. I am not sure whether it's possible using gtk to achieve this(display multiple videos on one gtk window)